# Recursive arithmetic sequence in Haskell

Tags: haskell

It's been nearly 30 years since I took an Algebra class and I am struggling with some of the concepts in Haskell as I work through [*Learn you a Haskell*](http://learnyouahaskell.com/chapters). The concept that I am working on now is "recursion". I have watched several youtube videos on the subject and found a site with the arithmetic sequence problem: a<sub>n</sub> = 8 + 3(a<sub>n-1</sub>) which I understand to be a<sub>n</sub> = a<sub>n-1</sub> + 3 This is what I have in Haskell.

```
addThree :: (Integral a) => a -> a
addThree 1 = 8
addThree n = (n-1) + 3
```

Running the script yields:

```
addThree 1
8
addThree 2
4
addThree 3
6
```

I am able to solve this and similar recursions on paper, (after polishing much rust), but do not understand the syntax in Haskell.

**My Question** How do I define the base and the function in Haskell as per my example?

---

If this is not the place for such questions, kindly direct me to where I should post. I see there are Stack Exchanges for Super User, Programmers, and Mathematics, but not sure which of the Stack family best fits my question.

Comment: you need to call `addThree` recursively and supply it `n-1` as argument

Comment: Surely "Learn you a Haskell" explains how to define simple recursive functions

Comment: @JohnColeman Yes. There are a few examples, but I am struggling to understand so that I can  apply them in the real world.

Answer (score 9):

First a *word* on Algebra and you problem: I think you are slightly wrong - if we write 3x it usually means 3*x (Mathematicans are even more lazy then programmers) so your series indeed should look like a<sub>n</sub> = 8 + 3*a<sub>n-1</sub> IMO

Then a<sub>n</sub> is the *n-th* element in a series of a's: a<sub>0</sub>, a<sub>1</sub>, a<sub>2</sub>, a<sub>3</sub>, ... that's why you there is a big difference between `(n-1)` and `addThree (n-1)` as the last one would designate a<sub>n-1</sub> while the first one would just be a number not really connected to your series.

---

Ok, let's have a look at your series a<sub>n</sub> = 8 + 3a<sub>n-1</sub> (this is how I would understand it - because otherwise you would have x=8+3*x and therefore just x = -4:

- you can choose a<sub>0</sub> - let's say it`s 0 (as you did?)
- then a<sub>1</sub>=8+3*0 = 8
- a<sub>2</sub>=8+3*8 = 4*8 = 32
- a<sub>3</sub>=8+3*32 = 8+3*32 = 104
- ...

ok let's say you want to use recursion than the problem directly translates into Haskell:

```
a :: Integer -> Integer
a 0 = 0
a n = 8 + 3 * a (n-1)

series :: [Integer]
series = map a [0..]
```

giving you (for the first 5 elements):

```
λ> take 5 series
[0,8,32,104,320]
```

---

Please note that this is a very bad performing way to do it - as the recursive call in `a` really does the same work over and over again.

A technical way to solve this is to observe that you only need the previous element to get the next one and use `Data.List.unfoldr`:

```
series :: [Integer]
series = unfoldr (\ prev -> Just (prev, 8 + 3 * prev)) 0
```

---

now of course you can get a lot more fancier with Haskell - for example you can define the series as it is (using Haskells laziness):

```
series :: [Integer]
series = 0 : map (\ prev -> 8 + 3 * prev) series
```

and I am sure there are much more ways out there to do it but I hope this will help you along a bit

Comment: Thank you. Thank you. Not only does this answer my question as to the syntax, there is much to refer back to as I continue to learn Haskell. BTW how did you enter the subscript?

Comment: @BrianWilson `<sub>Subscript</sup>`.

Comment: for the subscript you just have to use `a<sub>n-1</sub>` right in the text editor